# Maven3 profile with custom enforcer rule, is it possible?

Tags: maven-3, maven-enforcer-plugin, maven-profiles

I wrote and tested a custom enforcer rule to do distribution specific builds on various Linux distributions.  It tests well with the `mvn enforcer:enforce` command, with the provided `pom.xml` build snippet.

```xml
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-rule-redhat6x</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
      <rules>
        <redhat6x implementation="org.example.enforcer.Redhat6x">
          <compatible>true</compatible>
        </redhat6x>
      </rules>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce</id>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <goals>
      <goal>enforce</goal>
    </goals>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

After racking my brain and doing a lot of experimental testing, I cannot seem to find how to use this custom enforcer rule as a profile activation selector.

```xml
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>RedHat6x</id>
      <activation>
      <!-- Something goes here, but what?  This doesn't work -->
            <redhat6x implementation="com.cisco.tesdw.enforcer.Redhat6x">
              <compatible>true</compatible>
            </redhat6x>
      </activation>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

There are some hints that profile activation uses `maven-enforcer-rules` as detailed in the [Introduction to Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) page under the section "How can I tell which profiles are in effect during a build" section.  Namely, every profile activation which has multiple string values (os name, etc) is referred to the corresponding maven enforcer rule.  However, it seems that direct inclusion of a custom profile activator isn't obvious in the pom.xml, and [adding such would likely require a pom version update](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-settings/apidocs/org/apache/maven/settings/Activation.html).

Maven3 is also extensible in ways that are very flexible, is it possible to hook inclusion of my enforcer rule by the maven extensions mechanism?  There is documentation on how to include custom lifecycle participants; but, I fear that profile activation may have already occurred by the time the build starts.  Documentation is sparse, but the javadoc indicates that `AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(MavenSession session)` is called "after all `MavenProject` instances have been created".  This leaves some doubt in my mind whether it is called is before of after profile activation.  I suspect after, or how would one get a properly configured `MavenProject`?

Could someone tell me if profile activation customization is even remotely possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move plugin configuration under profile:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>RedHat6x</id>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.example</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-enforcer-rule-redhat6x</artifactId>
              <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
          <configuration>
            <rules>
              <redhat6x implementation="org.example.enforcer.Redhat6x">
                <compatible>true</compatible>
              </redhat6x>
            </rules>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>redhat-enforce</id>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <goals>
            <goal>enforce</goal>
          </goals>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand.  If I do this, won't it configure the enforcer rule _after_ I activate the profile?  I want the rule to _be_ the activation determination rule.  Still, I'll test it.

Comment: Ok, so to get plugins to work, I had to throw build tags around it.  Just as I suspected, it doesn't activate the profile, `mvn help:active-profiles` returns "There are no active profiles".

Comment: I see... Unfortunately the only way to activate certain profile is based on system or environment property. Those properties can't be set by any of the plugins, so you can only rely to one you set using -D flag in mvn command line or on one of environment variables on your system. See http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-activation.html